# How to do a 'where' query on a GORM object with matching local variable names

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Let's say I wish to search for a grails domain object, and the parameter values are in local variables whose names match the object's attribute names:

```
def getPerson(String firstName, String lastName) {
    Person person = Person.where {
        firstName == firstName
        lastName == lastName
    }
}
```

How can the query be written so that you find a person whose attributes match the local variable values?

Comment: Do you get an error? I tested with Grails 2.2.2, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the implicit `delegate` variable as follows:

```
def getPerson(String firstName, String lastName) {
    Person person = Person.where {
        delegate.firstName == firstName
        delegate.lastName == lastName
    }
}
```

Edit: This isn't necessary according to the [spec / test case](https://github.com/SpringSource/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm-test/src/test/groovy/grails/gorm/tests/WhereMethodSpec.groovy#L1409), but I find the explicit use of `delegate` easier to read/understand.

Comment: Cant use delegate.firstName = xx -- this will fail with error MultipleCompilationErrorsException Cannot query property "delegate"

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would avoid naming my method parameters such as my class attributes.
Then your GORM query could look like this:

```
def getPerson(String firstName, String lastName) {
    def query = Person.where {
        (firstName == p_firstName) && (lastName == p_lastName)
    }
    def results = query.list();
}
```

You can have a look here: http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#whereQueries